# Botium dialogflow agent not recognized properly

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am using `Botium` to validate dialog flow Intents and Training phrases. I have 3 agents in my dialog flow account.

In which one agent only recognizing all the intents `properly.others` are not. Mostly the intents using fulfillment responses are not recognized.

It is always calling the default fallback intent.

Can you help me solve this issue?

Both agents’ default language code are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Botium is using the [Dialogflow API](https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks). You have to make sure that the Botium capability ["DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE"](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-dialogflow#dialogflow_language_code) exactly matches your Dialogflow workspace, otherwise you will receive no responses at all.

So, in your botium.json, you should add something like this:

```
...
"DIALOGFLOW_LANGUAGE_CODE": "de"
...
```

See [this list](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/language) as reference.

Comment: Awesome! Please mark the answer as correct if you are satisfied.